# Remove page name from friendly URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have created a custom page inside Wordpress/Woocommerce which uses the site tamplate. I have a dynamic php page, inside the root folder of the site which generates links that I want to direct to my created custom Wordpress page. I want to have urls which look like this:

example.com/value1/value2.html

rather than the current Wordpress url I have which is:

example.com/page_name/value1/value2

So in essence I want my url to not display the page_name in the url and have .html at the end of the URL.

In my theme functions.php I have added two functions as suggested by [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

My functions are:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
            add_rewrite_tag('%value1%', '([^&]+)');
            add_rewrite_tag('%value2%', '([^&]+)');
        }
        add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
            add_rewrite_rule('^page_name/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=3090&value1=$matches[1]&value2=$matches[2]','top');
        }
        add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I have not specified a page name within wp-admin but I do have the page name inside the permalink. Looking at other similar questions I did see that someone said that removing the page name from the url is not possible because Wordpress/Woocommerce needs this as a reference point to the page it needs to display. Is this true? I have tried many permutations of .htaccess rules both inside and outside the Wordpress section.

I have managed to rewrite my php page by placing my rewrite rule outside the Wordpress block but I'm somehat stumped as to how I can just change the Wordpress URL as I want.

I have been left this problem by a former work college and it's giving me headaches as I have to find a solution.

**UPDATE

After Joe (many thanks) helped me I now have a situation where my final urls look like this:

https://example.com/page_name/value1/value2.html

however I still need /page_name/ to be removed from the URL. Anyone else have any suggestions on how to achieve this in Wordpress/Woocommerce?

Comment: That means you don't want to page-name on url - right?? and Let me know that what is role of value1 and value2 in example.com/page_name/value1/value2 this url??

Comment: Yes I don't wish page-name to appear in my url. Value1 and value2 are two database values I am getting from the database and passing into the page through the url. Those values are for a town name and a town id.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `page_name` from your URL easily using `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page_name/(.*) /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

This will leave you with your desired URL of `example.com/value1/value2`. You can see this working [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=844c0118-fd4e-5085-941a-0af50baadf8f). This is done use a 301 redirection, which is permanent, so I suggest while testing you change this to `R=302`.

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing.

Comment: ok will give this a go. Many thanks for your reply. Fingers crossed it works.

Comment: Morning Joe, nope didn't work. Still adding deltown into the url. I tried placing the rule outsite and inside the Wordpress block and also tried changing the link to the final page to exclude deltown from it but it still has /deltown/ in it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page_name/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

This is my Wordpress block in .htaccess

Comment: Right, apologies Joe. I'm an idiot. I didn't change the page_name in my .htaccess. I tried it and it does indeed remove page_name from the url. However, it brings up a page not found page.Again, tried it inside and outside the Wordpress htaccess block and same result. Again, apologies for the wasted replies.

Any ideas on how to get around this? Also how can I add .html to the end of the url?

Comment: haha hey @Rich ! Sounds like you've had an entertaining morning. Yes, my assumption on the `page not found` error is because it is not including `.html` in the rewrite. I've made an amendment to the `.htaccess` in my answer that will rewrite it to include `.html`. Give that a try :)

Comment: Yes Joe, very entertaining indeed haha. Well I have gotten close to my final goal. With your ammendment the url is now .html to the end. Thank you for that. Unfortunately I'm still getting a 404 page not found wordpress page when the url does not contain page-name. I'm beginning to think that what someone said about the page name having to be present in the url might be true and that I'm going to have to redirect all these pages manually. I hate rewriting and wordpress haha

Comment: Damn, it looks like this will need to be done manually I'm afraid Rich. Wordpress is an absolute nightmare when it comes to making changes like these. Good luck with further changes and if you have any other questions feel free to ping me on here. Btw, up the reds! (LFC fan haha).

Comment: Sadly looks that way, thanks for all your help Joe, really appreciate it. I won't hold your turn to the dark side against you mate. Haha, cheers. Anyone else have any ideas on how to get this done?